# Cron job not being able to start the process

Tags: linux, bash

I have the follwoing script which restarts memcache incase its down .

The problem is that , the script runs fine when i run it manually , but when i am making it run through cron job , the memcache is not being started .

```
#!/bin/bash
ps -eaf | grep 11211 | grep memcached
if [ $? -eq 1 ]
then
echo 'mmecache is down'
memcached -d -u nobody -l 10.1.1.1 -p 11211 -m 2076 -x 10.1.1.2 -v
else
echo "eq 0 - memcache running - do nothing"
fi
```

- - - - - /home/memcached_autorestartravi.sh >> /home/logs/memcache.log

I am getting this line under logs for every one minute , but i dont know why memcache is not being started .

```
echo 'mmecache is down'

echo 'mmecache is down'

echo 'mmecache is down'
```

Comment: you redirect **stderr**, too , to log. mostly got to do with *path* .

Comment: please tell me how can i redirect the stderr to the memcache log ??

Comment: /home/memcached_autorestartravi.sh >> /home/logs/memcache.log 2>&1

Comment: Is this cron job run by non-root?

Comment: How can i check that if the cron job is run by root or non root user ??

Comment: If it's in /etc/crontab or the job was set when running 'crontab -e' by root then it will run as root, otherwise not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is probably a PATH issue, memcached not being found when run from cron. Try using the full path to memcached.

Comment: WMR , i used the full path itself when mentioning inside the crontab -e

Comment: Thanks i redirected the errors .log , is started getting  memcached: command not found inside the error log .

Comment: Type "which memcached" and append full path to the memcached command in the cron job.

Comment: When i did which memcached and press Enter , i got /usr/local/bin/memcached , please tell me how can i give the memcached -d -u nobody -l 10.1.1.1 -p 11211 -m 2076 -x 10.1.1.2 -v

Comment: Change the line "memcached -d -u nobody -l 10.1.1.1 ..." to "/usr/local/bin/memcached -d -u nobody -l 10.1.1.1 ..." or add line "PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/bin" to the beginning of your cron job.

Comment: @PreethiJain Glad to be of a help. ;)